# Change line color of Google Charts Line/Area Chart between two data points

Tags: google-visualization

Is it possible to change a part of the line in a line or area chart from the Google Charts API?
For example like in this screenshot:[image]

If not, is there another way or API that could do this?

Comment: You can use the "certainty", "emphasis", and/or "scope" [column roles](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles) to change the presentation of a line.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find that myself, it's just what I'm looking for.